# Python program hangs in "poll" call with timeout

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to figure out why a Python program that I'm working on is hanging in some processes. The program uses both threads and processes. It uses multiprocessing PipeConnection objects to pass data between processes.

I have found part of the problem is that in one thread (which generates data and sends it to another process for use in calculations) a call to "poll" never returns:

```
            if calcDataPipe.poll(0.1):
```

calcDataPipe is a PipeConnection, created with "Pipe(True)" in the main thread - different from the calling thread.

Does anyone know of any reason why a "poll" call may fail to return? I though that the timeout would guarantee a return, but prints before and after the call clearly show that it doesn't.

Forgot to mention - I am working with CPython, 2.7.6

Edit:

This seems to have been caused by the amount of data in the queue - throttling the data transfer made the problem go away, though I wouldn't go so far as to call it a solution... This seems to be a (windows) CPython bug.

Comment: `poll` should actually [return immediately](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Connection.poll) if you *don't* specify a timeout: *"If timeout is not specified then it will return immediately"*.

Comment: Yes, it *should* return immediately, according to the documentation. Also according to the documentation it *should* return after a timeout if you specify a timeout.